# Cannot find symbol - HashMap .replace() method

Tags: java, hashmap

I am practicing using HashMap in JAVA from a tutorial. 
The sample HashMap implementation code fails to compile with the error:

```
DictionaryPractice.java:57: error: cannot find symbol
                              shoppingList.replace("Bread", Boolean.FALSE);
symbol:   method replace(String,Boolean)
location: variable shoppingList of type Map<String,Boolean>
```

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class DictionaryPractice {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Boolean> shoppingList = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();

        // Put some stuff in dictionary
        shoppingList.put("Ham", true);
        shoppingList.put("Bread", Boolean.TRUE);
        shoppingList.put("Oreos", Boolean.TRUE);
        shoppingList.put("Eggs", Boolean.FALSE);
        shoppingList.put("Sugar", false);

        // Retrieve items
        System.out.println(shoppingList.get("Ham"));
        System.out.println(shoppingList.get("Oreos"));

        // Remove things
        shoppingList.remove("Eggs");

        // Replace values for a certain key
        shoppingList.replace("Bread", Boolean.FALSE);
    }
}
```

I have read the JavaDocs on the HashMap class, and confirmed that `.replace` is a valid HashMap method to replace a value for a specified key. However, I keep getting the `cannot find symbol error`. Your kind help will be appreciated. Sorry for the basic question.
I am using jEdit Text Editor with the Compile plugin installed on a MacOSX Yosemite.

Comment: you can simply overwrite the the value since the hash map will overwrite the value of an existing key **shoppingList.put("Bread", Boolean.FALSE);** will do the job. another advice is to not mix types use either Boolean.FALSE or simply false

Comment: @whyn0t I think the tutorial uses both `Boolean` and `boolean` to demonstrate auto-boxing. The value stored is exactly the same.

Comment: @RealSkeptic i didn't say that it was wrong, it is just agood programming practice

Comment: @whyn0t Thanks for the advice. It is appreciated.

Comment: @RealSkeptic You're right. The tutorial varied between the reference and primitive types to demonstrate the implicit conversion that take place regardless of what you use (i.e. auto-boxing). Thank you much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method `replace(K,V)` in the `Map` interface is a new method introduced in Java 8.

Apparently, you are compiling your code with Java 7 or earlier.

Two possible solutions are:

1. [Download a Java 8 JDK for Mac OS X](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) and use that to compile your code.
2. Replace the `replace` with `put`. The method `replace` is a convenience method used when you don't want the new value to be placed in the map if the key doesn't have some value beforehand, similar to:

   ```
   if ( shoppingList.contains("Bread") ) {
        shoppingList.put("Bread",Boolean.FALSE);
   }
   ```

   In your case, since you `put` something for `Bread` a few lines earlier, `replace` would be unnecessary - you *know* that `Bread` is there. So just use `put` directly.

Comment: Thank you much. The issue has been resolved by following the instructions given. I downloaded and installed Java 8 JDK for Mac. The program aptly compiled.

Comment: Note that the code for Java7 should be `shoppingList.containsKey("Bread")`. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Comment: @andr There is no need for it here.